# Is there a better way to say "see someone's dreams"?

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language

By dream I mean the dreams you experience during sleep. Saying "see my dream" sounds weird, I think "experienced" would be a better word, but even then it sounds awkward.

The following example makes clear what I mean:

> Dreams are boring, but weird.
>
> You haven't seen my dreams, sweetheart. They're exciting and fun for
>   the most part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As James's answer mentions, this is a bit of an abstract concept to begin with, but

> You haven't dreamt my dreams.

might have the connotation that you are seeking.  This implies that the "sweetheart" has never experienced first-hand in his/her own dreams what the dreamer has experienced.

Answer (score 4):

"You haven't seen my dreams" is the best expression. It is a little weird, but the idea that you want to express is a little weird.

In the exact context, I'd probably just say "Not my dreams, they're exciting and fun"

In a wider sense, consider "You don't (or can't) share my dreams."

Answer (score 0):

When people talk about their dreams, they almost always talk about dreams they've *had*:

> You wouldn't believe the dream I **had** last night.
>   I've been **having** these strange dreams lately!

So, in your sentence, it would most likely be:

> You haven't **had** my dreams, sweetheart. They're exciting and fun for the most part.

---

It would be highly unusual for anybody to talk about *seeing* dreams. Especially since most people also hear things in dreams. (Other senses are also possible.) In fact, if you don't say that you've *had* a dream, you would just say, as you mention, that you've *experienced* a dream. But if you don't like how *experienced* sounds, go with *had*—which is more common.